# iOS 11: Size UICollectionView cells based on number of items in section (including placeholders)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, ios11

I'm aiming to lay out an editable collection view so that its contents fill the screen - the total width of each item in a given section should add to fill the collection view's width (with 1 line per section), and the total height of each section should add to fill the collection view's height.

The following code in gets me the kind of thing I want, and compensates for margins:

```
//in a UIViewController

override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let margin = (
        horizontal: collectionView.layoutMargins.left + collectionView.layoutMargins.right,
        vertical: collectionView.layoutMargins.top + collectionView.layoutMargins.bottom
    )
    return CGSize(
        width: (collectionView.bounds.width - margin.horizontal) / CGFloat(collectionView.numberOfItems(in: indexPath.section),
        height: (collectionView.bounds.height - margin.vertical) / CGFloat(collectionView.numberOfSections)
    )
}
```

With this, the items perfectly size to fill the screen - with one exception.

As of iOS 11, UICollectionViews now have automatic drag & drop placeholders which aren't exposed to the data source - something like `collectionView.numberOfItems(in: indexPath.section)` will report the same number whether there's a placeholder present or not. The result is the items in a section overflow into a second line when a placeholder is added during a drop.

However, it seems Apple has silently added UIDataSourceTranslating, which lets us get around this problem to some extent:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let margin = (
        horizontal: collectionView.layoutMargins.left + collectionView.layoutMargins.right,
        vertical: collectionView.layoutMargins.top + collectionView.layoutMargins.bottom
    )
    var itemsInSection = 0
    var numberOfSections = 0
    //undocumented, but seems to work as the name suggests in this example:
    collectionView.performUsingPresentationValues {
        itemsInSection = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: indexPath.section)
        numberOfSections = collectionView.numberOfSections
    }
    return CGSize(
        width: (collectionView.bounds.width - margin.horizontal) / CGFloat(itemsInSection),
        height: (collectionView.bounds.height - margin.vertical) / CGFloat(collectionView.numberOfSections)
    )
}
```

This sort of works - regular items in the section shrink when a placeholder is added. However, this still doesn't reliably prevent sections overflowing onto second lines. Perhaps it doesn't resize the placeholder?

Does anyone have a solution for sizing everything correctly, which accounts for drag & drop?